# Export a whole world as a mesh

Tags: mesh

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to  export a whole world as a single mesh file?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6587/export-a-whole-world-as-a-mesh/) by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 349 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8531/mcamurri/) on 2019-06-26**:
Any update on this? The issue is still open but maybe there are third party programs? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Short answer: No

It would be feasible to support exporting the world to a single collada file. This would require a bit of work. I suggest submitting a feature request on the gazebo issue tracker.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) on 2014-07-16**:
Done in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1230/support-for-exporting-a-world-as-a-single

**Comment by [CR7](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27336/cr7/) on 2020-06-15**:
@ffurrer can u please share this snippet.